# Starting rails server on a particular port on Debian boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, rvm, debian

This isn't exactly a production deployment of rails, or I'd go the standard Passenger route - I simply want it to start on port 3003 and sit there.

I'm running the following `.sh` script from `rc.local`

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby /root/rails_app/script/rails server -d --port 3003
```

I seem to recall the first line is required by rvm to enable ruby\rails commands in the shell. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do the trick.

I'm having a hard time diagnosing the issue.

Is there a way to see the error log of scripts that are executed via `rc.local`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not `source` RVM in `sh` shell, you need to use a wrapper:

```
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby \
  /root/rails_app/script/rails server -d --port 3003
```

you can find more information about it here - http://rvm.io/integration/init-d